# Django TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'

Tags: python, django, model

I have just changed my models and done all the necesarry migrations but I keep getting problems. I've tried adding a new record to my missions table after I did the 'runserver' command. This is the error I got:

```
TypeError at /admin/missions/mission/add/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/missions/mission/add/
Django Version: 1.9.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _clone, line 1062
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Python34\\Scripts\\heroesForHire',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 22 Feb 2016 22:37:29 +0000
```

This is what my missions model looks like:

```
from django_pg import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
OUTCOME_CHOICES = (
    ('U', 'Unsuccessful'),
    ('S', 'Successful'),
)

class Team (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField
    leader = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    members = models.TextField

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    citizenship = models.CharField(max_length = 40)

class Mission(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    description = models.TextField
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description, self.location, self.difficulty

class Report(models.Model):
    mission = models.ForeignKey('Mission')
    outcome = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = OUTCOME_CHOICES)
    comments = models.TextField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.outcome
```

Here is what appears in my command prompt:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 22, 2016 - 23:02:00
Django version 1.9.1, using settings 'heroesForHire.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[22/Feb/2016 23:02:15] "GET /admin/missions/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3452
[22/Feb/2016 23:02:40] "GET /admin/missions/mission/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[22/Feb/2016 23:02:42] "GET /admin/missions/mission/?e=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1114
[22/Feb/2016 23:02:44] "GET /admin/missions/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3452
Internal Server Error: /admin/missions/mission/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, i
n get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, i
n get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 541
, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in
_wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57
, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 244,
in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 143
5, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _
wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in
_wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in b
ound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 136
7, in changeform_view
    ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 605
, in get_form
    fields = flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 296
, in get_fieldsets
    return [(None, {'fields': self.get_fields(request, obj)})]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 594
, in get_fields
    form = self.get_form(request, obj, fields=None)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 639
, in get_form
    return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 545, in mode
lform_factory
    return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 247, in __ne
w__
    opts.field_classes)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 176, in fiel
ds_for_model
    formfield = formfield_callback(f, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 145
, in formfield_for_dbfield
    formfield = self.formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 228
, in formfield_for_foreignkey
    return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line
942, in formfield
    'queryset': self.remote_field.model._default_manager.using(db),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122, in
 manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 997, in u
sing
    clone = self._clone()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1062, in
_clone
    clone = self.__class__(model=self.model, query=query, using=self._db, hints=
self._hints)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'
[22/Feb/2016 23:03:21] "GET /admin/missions/mission/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 163527
```

Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this please?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Do you mean a screen shot of the command prompt while the server is running?

Comment: You are on Django 1.9.1, but it looks like latest django-pgfields doesn't even support Django 1.7 yet?

Comment: So what you're say is that I shouldn't use composite fields? Or I shouldn't use PostgreSQL at all?